# Control not initialized in Edge/IE on Page_Init()

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Is there a different order of calling the constructors for controls depending on the browser brand?

In my project there is a DevExpress Captcha control, it's rendered in a MyForm.aspx page. When I open the app in Chrome/Firefox, it works fine, there is a random string inside Code property, but when I open the same page in Edge/IE, it is always null (even inside Page_Init), so it returns false always.

I thought maybe there is different order of calling the constructor for this control depending on the browser, what else could be the reason that this control is not initialized in some browsers and others yes?

```
public partial class MyForm: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string CaptchaCode { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptchaCode = Captcha.Code;
    }

    protected void btnPurchaseCardSecurity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // line breaks added for readability. [ed]
        Captcha.IsValid = string.Equals(Request.Params["Captcha$TB"]
            .Replace('o', '0').Replace('i', 'l'), CptCode,   
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Bellow is the control in aspx

```
<dx:ASPxCaptcha ID="Captcha" runat="server">
    <ChallengeImage />
</dx:ASPxCaptcha>
```

Comment: You could easily test yourself what the order is yourself if you have doubts. No need to waste time asking a question. Just attach your debugger and set breakpoints. Or add logging.

Comment: I did, have not find anything except the things I mentioned, something might be happening behind which is not obvious going through debugging

Comment: If you set breakpoints, you would find clear answers to your questions about whether the order changes with different browsers.

Comment: Of course, I set those and the order is the same, but the values are not, and how does a browser affect what's on the serverside?

Comment: I've solved this, and the answer is bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still struggling to get this working on Edge/IE but so far I have discovered what's causing the trouble. DevExpress captcha component might not be working when you access the page via HTTP instead of HTTP protocol IF inside the web.config requireSSL is set to true. So for now, everything shows up using HTTP, it just doesn't transfer the initialized value of the captcha UI-serverside wise in Edge, but it does in Chrome and Firefox.

I can't access the site using HTTPS.

> **ASPxCaptcha does not work with HTTP when RequireSSL is set in the web.config**
>
> ASPxCaptcha does not work with HTTP when RequireSSL is set to True in the web.config, because cookies are secured in this case and ASPxCaptcha cannot get the session ID that is stored in them.
> Thus, it is necessary to use HTTPS in this case.

For all those having a similar problem go check out this link for other possible solutions:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18582/how-to-resolve-issues-with-aspxcaptcha

One of the things that helped is going to project properties > Web > Servers and replacing Project URL's HTTP to HTTPS from the URL of the project. Than VS asked me to install SSL certificate. Accessing the site via https and everything works!